# Store SVN revision # to variable after a commit

Tags: svn

I'm using a program to perform SVN merges across different branches....When I perform a commit, I get the following output:

Transmitting file data .
Committed revision XXX.

I need to take the value of XXX and store it to a variable to be used in my next command....I've searched and searched and can't figure out how to extract this number.

Comment: I don't even know what TO try....i've searched here and Google and can't find an answer to this. I just want to be able to do something like this:

svn commit -m 'test'
$commitNumber = X

(where X is the committed revision number of the previous line)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it....I was looking for an SVN command to do this instead of just putting the command output into a variable. I used the following code:

```
$output = svn commit -m 'test' | Out-String
$revStart = $output.IndexOf('revision') + 9
$revLength = $output.IndexOf('.',$revStart) - $revStart
$revision = $output.Substring($revStart, $revLength)
```

Comment: Looks reasonable.  For future questions, you should say what technologies you're working with; e.g. here it's Powershell.  Just asking for code to do something will likely get your question closed as it's far too broad and not helpful to you either.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry about that. The only reason I didn't mention Powershell was because I was thinking that there would be an SVN command to do what I needed that would be independent of the language I was working in. That was my bad, I was thinking about it all wrong.